# Dijkstra's algorithm average runtime change based on complexity

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory, path-finding, dijkstra

Dijkstra algorithm with a self-balancing binary search tree has a complexity of O(e * log(n)). Does this mean that in a statistical middle, pathfinding queries for e=100 and n=25 take double the time than pathfinding queries for e=50 and n=25.

The question is kind of pumpy, my point is about a relative comparison of statistically average runtime changes.

Comment: Title is completely misleading, try to reformulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think math is simple here, with `O(E * log(N))` average running time is proportional to E. O(n) can in reality be `O(n) + C`, so with small `n` and significant `C` the `n*2` will be not two times slower but less: `(2n + C) / (n + C)`.

Comment: I do not really get the second part of your answer. In the first part you say that the running time is proportional to the number of edges. So that means doubling the amount of edges will double the average running time. In the second part of your answer your refer to n*2, which would be refer to a doubling of the node count, right?

Comment: @Tim91 in second part I use generic n, as just a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find it interesting: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=complexity2

Check the heading "The recursion tree"